# ¿Por que al compilar en ionic como --prod no funciona mi aplicación?

Tags: ionic, build

Compilando mi proyecto con `ionic cordova build android` mi aplicación corre sin problemas. Pero al hacerlo para producción `ionic cordova build android --prod` no pasa del SplashScreen, quedándose la pantalla en blanco.

No sé si tendrá algo que ver, pero uso una página inicial para comprobaciones, desde la cual voy cargando la página correspondiente: login, registro, home.

He accedido a la consola de chrome compilando con --prod y me aparece el siguiente error:

> 08:46:26.343 Native: tried calling File.dataDirectory, but the File plugin is not
>   installed. E @ vendor.js:1
>
> 08:46:26.348 Install the File  plugin: 'ionic cordova
>   plugin add cordova-plugin-file' E @ vendor.js:1
>
> 08:46:26.366 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'replace' of null
>       at new o (main.js:1)
>       at vendor.js:1
>       at re (vendor.js:1)
>       at ne (vendor.js:1)
>       at vendor.js:1
>       at re (vendor.js:1)
>       at ne (vendor.js:1)
>       at t.get (vendor.js:1)
>       at Te (vendor.js:1)
>       at Se (vendor.js:1)

El plugin 'cordova-plugin-file' está instalado correctamente, he probado a reinstalarlo y a instalar otras versiones.

Gracias y un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisa la ruta `plugins\cordova-plugin-file` de la carpeta de tu proyecto y si no vez unos archivos parecidos a estos https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file ese plugin esta dañado.

Si es el caso ejecuta esto:

```
ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-file --save
```

Asegúrate de que se aya eliminado completamente la carpeta `cordova-plugin-file` adentro de la carpeta `plugins`, si no eliminala manualmente.

Si necesitas ese plugin instalalo nuevamente con:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file --save
```

Y asegúrate que se aya instalado correctamente en su carpeta.

Comment: Muchas gracias Juan, 
parece ser que en algunas ocasiones el plugin aparece como corrupto y es necesario realizar la reinstalación. Lo he probado y ha funcionado.